# Moving circles, passing through 3 points

Tags: geometry, circles

I would like to know if there is an unique solution or at least a good approximation for the following problem:

I have three points in a space forming a triangle. There is nothing special for this triangle, it is not equilateral, but if we find a solution for an equilateral triangle, we can approximate it to that.

The points are `(0,18.27)`, `(24.58,34.37)` and `(24.82,0)` and I have the exactly time when a moving circle touches each point for the first time.

The assumptions are:

- The circle moves at a constant speed at a constant direction;
- I only know the first time it touch the points, not the time it touch with the other half;
- The radius is, at least 20 (the circle that circumscribe the points) and at most 200;
- It can come from any direction;

**The main objective:**

**To have some characteristic length scale of those moving circles, e.g. its radius.**

I am looking for a general solution for that. The thing is: I have a spatial data from three points and I could identify a particular thing happening at in the time series from the three points. From the theory behind this natural phenomena, I could approximate it to a circle. So, I am assuming that this is a moving circle that pass through three points.

I added a figure to illustrate the problem. T_pi is the time the circle touches each point.

[image]

I also made another figure to ilustrate what I think are the variables of the problem: radius, angle, offset and speed. I am assuming that they are constant for each circle.

[image]

Feel free to ask for more information about the problem and if we can make any other assumption about that.

Comment: You have described your setup, but it is not clear what you want to calculate exactly ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving attention to the problem. I edited the post to stress the main objective of the problem. Is it better?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting this post. I am not trying to approximate a circle from three points. I have three points that are touched by a moving circle at different times and I would like to know the radius of that moving circle.

Comment: Your ask is still not clear. Moving or otherwise, as long as it is circle through 3 non-collinear points, it is unique. Do you just want radius of this circle and not necessarily its center?

Comment: It would be great to have the center as well, but the main objective is to have the radius. The only information I have about the circles is the time it touches each point for the first time.

Comment: @MathLover I believe the circle is being translated.  (It moves with constant speed and direction).  For each point, we are given the first time the moving circle coincides with it.

Comment: Can you tell us the times at which the circle touches the points?  Or are you looking for a general solution?

Comment: The coordinates of the three points are given by the problem. But if I need to approximate it to an Equilateral triangle, I am fine with that. I added a figure and more explanation to the post. Sorry if it seems confusing.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for adding the diagram.

Comment: I added another figure with what I think are the variables of the problem.

Comment: If center of the circle of radius $r$ is moving along a line $y = mx + c$ and say when it touches the first point $A$, its center is at $(x_1, y_1)$ . We then have $y_1 = m x_1 + c, \sqrt{(a_1-x_1)^2 + (a_2-y_1)^2} = r$. Now we know the time to the second point $B$. We know the new center will be $(x_1 + \frac{v t}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}, y_1 + \frac{m v t}{\sqrt{m^2+1}})$ where $v$ is the speed. We can again use the distance formula between center and $B$ and equate to $r$. We can do the same for third point.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer yet, just an attempt to formulate the problem.  It really should be a comment, but it won't fit in a comment box.

The center of the circle moves along a straight line with constant velocity.  We can say that at time $t$ it is at the point$$(x_0+at, y_0+bt)$$ where $x_0,y_0,a,\text{ and }b$ are unknown constants.  At times $t_1<t_2<t_3$ the point is a some fixed, but unknown distance $r$ from the points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$, respectively, where $t_i,x_i,y_i$ are given for $i=1,2,3$.

That gives us $3$ equations in $5$ unknowns:
$$(x_0+at_i-x_i)^2+(y_0+bt_i-y_i)^2=r^2,\ i=1,2,3$$

I've been trying to eliminate one or more unknowns.  Of course, we can eliminate $r$, by just saying the the distances are equal, but this eliminates an equation, so we have $2$ equations in $4$ unknowns.  I don't see how to eliminate any other variables.  $(x_0, y_0)$ is the position of the moving point at time $t=0$.  We can reset the origin of the time scale, say by setting $t_i'=t_i-t_1$, but that doesn't eliminate the unknowns $x_0, y0$.  Similarly, it's only the ratio of $b$ to $a$ that's really fixed, but $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the distance the point moves in one unit of time, and I don't see any way around this.

Since we have more unknowns that equations, I tend to believe that there is not a unique solution to the system.  If the OP would gives us the values of $t_1,t_2,t_3$, I think I could demonstrate this.

**EDIT**

I recognize that I haven't taken cognizance of the requirements that the times are the first time the circle passes through the points, or the restrictions on the radius, but I don't think that this will change matters.  This is just a gut feeling.  I think there are infinitely many solutions to the system, and we'll be able to pick out more than one that meet the requirements.  (Of course, I'm wrong a lot.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me to formulate the problem. I started thinking if it could lead to an unique solution if we have any first guess for a and b, for instance. These circles are moving atmospheric features and I have the wind velocity at the points. The only problem is that the wind is too gusty for me to trust it beyond as a first guess. But it could simply the problem.

Comment: Trying a few guesses at the wind velocity might help.  Also, is it possible to take measurements at more than $3$ points?

Comment: I only have three points. How do you think I could use the wind velocity as a guess for this problem?

Comment: I mean if you take the average wind velocity from your measurements, and find a solution to your problem, you can see if it seems reasonable, given your knowledge of the problem.  If it seems wrong, you can modify the wind velocity a bit and see if that gives a more reasonable solution.